# libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-compiling, yocto

I am cross compiling the application where host system is Ubuntu 16.04 (using `gcc5` and `g++5`) and target is Renesas R-Car H3ULCB.

I am using cross compilation environment which was created using yocto build for H3ULCB. I have created CMake file for for project build.
While cross compilation, there is error for linking the shared object libraries for libc.

Below is the error:

```
/opt/poky/2.1.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-ld:
/home/microsar/SIP/CBD1800182-D06/delivery-CBD1800182-D06/builds/cross/amsr-vector-fs-libosabstraction/lib/libosabstraction.a(scheduler.cc.o):
undefined reference to symbol 'sched_get_priority_min@@GLIBC_2.17'
01:35:13 [  ERROR]
/opt/poky/2.1.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Below is the content of `.cmake` file:

```
# Poky installation specific
set(POKY_INSTALL_DIR "/opt/poky/2.1.3")
set(POKY_TARGET_BIN_DIR
    "${POKY_INSTALL_DIR}/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux")
#set(POKY_POOL_DIR "${PIKEOS_INSTALL_DIR}/aarch64-poky-linux/arm/v8hf")
#set(CUSTOM_POOL_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/build/pikeos_pool")

# Use the PikeOS pool as sysroot
#set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${CUSTOM_POOL_DIR}")
# Set the install prefix to a reasonable default value.
#set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CUSTOM_POOL_DIR}/usr" CACHE STRING "Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.")

# Set the name of the target systems
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
# Set the version of the target system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 2.1.3)
# Set processor (or hardware) of the target system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)


# sysroot location
set(MYSYSROOT /opt/poky/2.1.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux)
# Set C compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${POKY_TARGET_BIN_DIR}/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc)
# Set C++ compiler
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${POKY_TARGET_BIN_DIR}/aarch64-poky-linux-g++)
# compiler
include(CMakeForceCompiler) 
cmake_force_c_compiler(/opt/poky/2.1.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc
   GNU)
cmake_force_cxx_compiler(/opt/poky/2.1.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++
   GNU)
# compiler/linker flags
add_definitions("--sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl
   --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}
   --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
# cmake built-in settings to use find_xxx() functions
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${MYSYSROOT})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
# Set linker calling command rule
# !!! Order of parameters is important here !!!
# Otherwise you will get plenty of unresolved STL symbols during linking!
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE   "<CMAKE_LINKER> -o <TARGET>
   <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS>"  
   CACHE STRING "Linker calling command rule for C++ executables." FORCE
   )

set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE
   "<CMAKE_LINKER> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS <LINK_FLAGS>"
    CACHE STRING "Linker calling command rule for C executables." FORCE )
```

Comment: I have formatted the code. For unknown reason, this formatting included splitting the lines, so, please, check that resulted code corresponds to the one you actually have. And next time, please, format the code by yourself; for that purpose you may use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: Hint about setting `sysroot` in CMake: CMake has special variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html). Once this variable set, you no longer need to explicitly  add `--sysroot` option.

Comment: Can't you use Yocto SDK to handle cross-compilation? When you create it, it generates an environment setup i.e `/opt/sdk/2.6.1/environment-setup-corei7-64-arch-linux`, and when you source it, it set cmake to use cross-compilation and correct sysroot.

Comment: Yocto SDK is already used to setup the cross-compilation environment for Renesas. I need to integrate Adaptive Autosar build environment with it. For this I have updated the toolchain file. While building the Adaptive Autosar stack with cross compilation environment , mentioned error was shown.